# Detect a right-click on Ace editor

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contextmenu, ace-editor

Is there a way to detect a right-click event on Ace editor?

I've being trying to add a listener like this:

```js
  editor.session.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('success!');
      return false;
  }, false);
```

and this

```js
  editor.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('success!');
      return false;
  }, false);
```

but without success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add event listener on the element containing the editor

```
editor.container.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('success!');
    return false;
}, false);
```