# How to disable Copy, Paste and Droping text in ng2-ace-editor

Tags: angular, typescript, ace-editor

Is there is any way to disable Copy, Paste and Dropping text in ng2-ace-editor.
https://github.com/fxmontigny/ng2-ace-editor This is the one I have used in my angular 5 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to disable clipboard add the following command:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "breakTheEditor", 
    bindKey: "ctrl-c|ctrl-v|ctrl-x|ctrl-shift-v|shift-del|cmd-c|cmd-v|cmd-x", 
    exec: function() {} 
});
```

to disable dragging use

```
![
    "dragenter", "dragover", "dragend", "dragstart", "dragleave", "drop"
].forEach(function(eventName) {
    editor.container.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    }, true)
});
editor.setOption("dragEnabled", false)
```

Comment: Thanks, Works good.
disable clipboard using key working but in browser we have a paste option in edit menu, how to prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can benefit from this issue on github https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/266

To hide cursor and line highlights

```
editor.setOptions({
    readOnly: true,
    highlightActiveLine: false,
    highlightGutterLine: false
})
```

`editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.element.style.opacity=0`
to make editor non tabbable

```
editor.textInput.getElement().tabIndex=-1
```

or

```
editor.textInput.getElement().disabled=true
```

to disable all shortcuts

```
editor.commands.commmandKeyBinding={}
```

Comment: If I set `readOnly: true ` then I can't able to type content.
I need to type content but need to disable copy, paste and drop content

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer for RMB [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320574/detect-a-right-click-on-ace-editor)

```
editor.container.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('success!');
    return false;
}, false);
```